# Travis CI throws Syntax Error

Tags: python, django, travis-ci

I am trying to build a Django project with Travis
My builds keep showing the error below

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
/home/travis/build.sh: line 298: syntax error in conditional expression
/home/travis/build.sh: line 298: syntax error near `2.7/bin/activate'
/home/travis/build.sh: line 298: `if [[ ! -f ~/virtualenv/python– 2.7/bin/activate ]]; then'
```

Here is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: python
services:
  – mysql
python:
  – 2.7
env:
  - DJANGO=1.9.2

before_install:
  - export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=happny.settings.travis
install:
  – pip install -r requirements/test.txt

before_script:
  – python manage.py makemigrations
  – python manage.py migrate
script:
  – python manage.py test
branches:
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: You have a space in `~/virtualenv/python– 2.7/bin/activate` that shouldn't be there. Between `python-` and `2.7`.

Comment: Thanks alot. I finally figured out the issue was from my yml formatting.
I was using a wrong dash character (-). i have copied a sample .travis.yml file from a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the dash (-) character in the yaml file. Copying from a web page resulted in some formatting mismatch

I noticed the length of the dash was longer than normal. I fixed it by retyping the .travis.yml file by hand.

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the python version in ""

```
python:
  - "2.7"
```